# AspNetCore 2.0 Cookie Authentication based on context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

I'm using `AddAuthentication` in a `netcoreapp2.0` and I need to have different configurations based on current `HttpContext`.

Since 2.0 with [the auth changes](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/262), in `Configure` it is no longer possible to use

```
///NOT WORKING IN 2.0 - Obsolete
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    //...
});

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
{
    //...
}
```

I was using those options to customize auth based on a value in the `HttpContext` in `app.UseWhen(...)`

Now the configuration is performed via services:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Cookies")
    .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
    {
        //...
    });
```

However, services `ConfigureServices` are instantiated before the `app` in `Configure`, hence no context yet in the pipeline.
Is there any workaround to replicate this sort of configuration?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same result with two Transient services `services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, ConfigureMyCookie>();` and `services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions>, ConfigureMyGoogleCookie>();`, see PR here: https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit/pull/96

Comment: What kind of configuration changes? And based on what aspects of HttpContext?

Answer (score 0):

You can add two Cookie authentication schemes and on your controller specify to use either one you need.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services
            .AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie("Cookie1", option1 =>
            {
                // config cookie1
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookie2", option2 =>
            {
                // config cookie2
            });
    }
}

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Cookie1")]
public class FooController
{

}

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Cookie2")]
public class BarController
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks Kahbazi, I'm actually looking into having one authorization scheme that changes its options based on the request.

Comment: can you tell a example. what would you do on old katana/owin?